# Dramatic speed improvement breaking SQL Server batch into two

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server code is completely stumping me with its query execution time.

I have a a lot (around 60) joins I need to do, and my original sub-query rich query started executing unpredictably.  I then followed accepted wisdom and broke it into two temporary tables.  The batch to do this looks something like:

```
1. SELECT INTO #tempIndexTable
2. SELECT INTO #TableA FROM #tempIndexTable LEFT JOIN {a bunch of sub queries}
3. SELECT INTO #TableB FROM #tempIndexTable LEFT JOIN {a bunch of different sub queries}
```

#tempIndexTable has a clustered index on the column used for the joins in 2. and 3.

What happens is that if I run all three statements as a batch, the run time is 2.5 minutes plus.

If however I run the above as two batches (1+2; 3) the run time is 25 seconds.

EDIT: The data itself is not a lot of data - maybe 6000 rows on a machine that doesn't see Pagefile usage at any point.

Can anyone help with why this might be?  I can see good reasons why running the same query twice will yield a different result (not the case here), or it making a difference whether it's in a procedure or a batch.  But neither is the case here.  I'd really like to run this as a single batch because I use variables which would need to be re-defined again in every single batch which is mucky.

Or maybe another way of putting the same question is what is it that takes place at the end of a batch which doesn't take place between two SQL statements within a batch?

To make things worse:
- This is all on SQL Server 2000.  Yes.
- I don't have access to Server Management studio so looking at query execution plans is tough

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your working set becomes large enough to cause swapping when you run the whole thing as a single batch. This is probably a consequence of the effects on implicit transaction boundaries.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I don't think it's this.  Edited questiion to add more info - the machine never gets into the swapping and the number of rows is small - only around 6k.

Answer (score 0):

I might well be on the wrong track, but what is the total size of the script? I've seen the query optimizer work overtime on scripts in the tens of kilobytes range, such as the case where the initial population of the #tempIndexTable is a whole bundle of insert statements.

If you're problem repeatably goes away when breaking it into batches, simply add a `GO` statement between each select. This breaks the script into multiple batches while keeping the   same session.